# Is it possible to change scope for parts of playground (to play with access control)

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I curious is it possible to split Swift playground so that different parts will be in different source files, different modules?

Inside playground package I found file with format "section-1.swift", I tried to add "section-2.swift"... nothing. Any clues?

Update: I asked same question on dev forum https://devforums.apple.com/thread/239671?tstart=50

Answer (score 0):

The "section" files inside a playground are all stitched together into a single implicit Swift source file, and treated as a single module.

To play with access control, you'll need to build an app project (possibly with an embedded framework target).

Comment: It is a shame. Should be a way to have examples of access control in playgrounds. I will ask swift team on the forum for their plans on this.

Comment: If there's behavior you want to see, [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) might help, too.